# D3js Scale and Translate not working with buttons (Zoom and Pan )

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to zoom and pan with d3js. I have attached the code below. I am using d3js v6
zoom is not working currently v6 code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Zoom + Pan</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<style>
.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="buttons">
<button class="zooming" id="zoom_in">+</button>
<button class="zooming" id="zoom_out">-</butto/*n>
<button class="panning" id="pan_right">&rarr;</button>
<button class="panning" id="pan_left">&larr;</button>
<button class="panning" id="pan_top">&darr;</button>
<button class="panning" id="pan_top">&uarr;</button>
</div>
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var randomX = d3.randomNormal(width / 2, 80),
    randomY = d3.randomNormal(height / 2, 80);

var data = d3.range(2000).map(function() {
    return [randomX(), randomY() ];
});

var zoom = d3.bheviour.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).translateExtent([
        [ -1000, -500 ],
        [ 1000, 500 ]
    ]).on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .call(zoom)
  .append("g");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; });

function zoomed() {
    svg.attr("transform",
        "translate(" + [d3.zoomTransform(this).x,d3.zoomTransform(this).y] + ")" +
        "scale(" + d3.zoomTransform(this).k + ")"
    );
}

async function interpolateZoom (translate, scale) {
    var self = this;
    await d3.transition().duration(350).tween("zoom", function () {
        var iTranslate = d3.interpolate([d3.zoomTransform(this).x,d3.zoomTransform(this).y], translate),
            iScale = d3.interpolate( d3.zoomTransform(this).k, scale);
        return function (t) {
            d3.zoomIdentity
                .scale(scale)
                .translate(translate);
            zoomed();
        };
    });
}

function zoomClick(event) {
    var clicked = event.target,
        direction = 1,
        factor = 0.2,
        target_zoom = 1,
        center = [width / 2, height / 2],
        extent = zoom.scaleExtent(),
        translate = [d3.zoomTransform(this).x,d3.zoomTransform(this).y],
        scale = d3.zoomTransform(this).k,
        translate0 = [],
        l = [],
        view = {x: translate[0], y: translate[1], k: scale};

    event.preventDefault();
    direction = (this.id === 'zoom_in') ? 1 : -1;
    target_zoom = scale * (1 + factor * direction);

    if (target_zoom < extent[0] || target_zoom > extent[1]) { return false; }

    translate0 = [(center[0] - view.x) / view.k, (center[1] - view.y) / view.k];
    view.k = target_zoom;
    l = [translate0[0] * view.k + view.x, translate0[1] * view.k + view.y];

    view.x += center[0] - l[0];
    view.y += center[1] - l[1];
    console.log(view.x,view.y, view.k);
    interpolateZoom([view.x, view.y], view.k);
}
d3.selectAll('button').on('click', zoomClick);

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Zoom + Pan</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<style>
.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="buttons">
<button class="zooming" id="zoom_in">+</button>
<button class="zooming" id="zoom_out">-</butto/*n>
<button class="panning" id="pan_right">&rarr;</button>
<button class="panning" id="pan_left">&larr;</button>
<button class="panning" id="pan_top">&darr;</button>
<button class="panning" id="pan_top">&uarr;</button>
</div>
<script>
var width = 960,
height = 500;

var randomX = d3.randomNormal(width / 2, 80),
randomY = d3.randomNormal(height / 2, 80);

var data = d3.range(2000).map(function() {
return [randomX(), randomY() ];
});

var zoom = d3.bheviour.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).translateExtent([
    [ -1000, -500 ],
    [ 1000, 500 ]
]).on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
.call(zoom)
  .append("g");

svg.append("rect")
.attr("class", "overlay")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 2.5)
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; });

function zoomed() {
svg.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + [d3.zoomTransform(this).x,d3.zoomTransform(this).y] + ")" +
    "scale(" + d3.zoomTransform(this).k + ")"
);
}

async function interpolateZoom (translate, scale) {
var self = this;
await d3.transition().duration(350).tween("zoom", function () {
    var iTranslate = d3.interpolate([d3.zoomTransform(this).x,d3.zoomTransform(this).y], translate),
        iScale = d3.interpolate( d3.zoomTransform(this).k, scale);
    return function (t) {
        d3.zoomIdentity
            .scale(scale)
            .translate(translate);
        zoomed();
    };
});
}

function zoomClick(event) {
var clicked = event.target,
    direction = 1,
    factor = 0.2,
    target_zoom = 1,
    center = [width / 2, height / 2],
    extent = zoom.scaleExtent(),
    translate = [d3.zoomTransform(this).x,d3.zoomTransform(this).y],
    scale = d3.zoomTransform(this).k,
    translate0 = [],
    l = [],
    view = {x: translate[0], y: translate[1], k: scale};

event.preventDefault();
direction = (this.id === 'zoom_in') ? 1 : -1;
target_zoom = scale * (1 + factor * direction);

if (target_zoom < extent[0] || target_zoom > extent[1]) { return false; }

translate0 = [(center[0] - view.x) / view.k, (center[1] - view.y) / view.k];
view.k = target_zoom;
l = [translate0[0] * view.k + view.x, translate0[1] * view.k + view.y];

view.x += center[0] - l[0];
view.y += center[1] - l[1];
console.log(view.x,view.y, view.k);
interpolateZoom([view.x, view.y], view.k);
}
d3.selectAll('button').on('click', zoomClick);

</script>
```

Comment: Please explain where does variable `event` come from?

Comment: I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

You are using **D3 V6**. `d3.event.target` is supported until **V5**. From **V6** onwards, use event passed as the first parameter to your callback function:

```
function zoomClick(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;
  ...
}

...

d3.selectAll('button').on('click', zoomClick);
```

Comment: I made some changes to the code. How to make the Pan buttons to work?

Comment: You have an error here: `<button class="zooming" id="zoom_out">-</butto/*n>`. Please check your code very carefully